# How to fetch ParentRoleId in Validation Rule from a Custom Lookup to User

Tags: validation, user-record, role-hierarchy

I need to compare the parentroleid or Name of the parent role, of two lookup fields to user
however am able to get logged in user's parent role i,e

`($UserRole.ParentRole.Name)` works but

`[CustomUserLookup__r.UserRole.ParentRole.Name]` throws error `Field ParentRole Does not exist`

Comment: From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_role.htm) it appears ParentRoleId is a simple reference without relationship. Not sure how you make `UserRole.ParentRole.Name` work. Try `UserRole.ParentRoleId` - and this should also work for `CustomUserLookup__r.UserRole.ParentRoleId`. (But is `CustomUserLookup__r` not rather a hierarchical relationship instead of a lookup?! You start from the User, right?)

Comment: Sorry didnt get your question, CustomUserLookup is a field with lookup relationship to the user